# Spliting String with delimiter and holding the values

Tags: java, string

Since I am making a simple Mastermind game, which is going to be played in the console, my task includes starting the game with entering sth like this: "start 4 5 34356". Where start initializes the game, 4 is the number of possible tries to guess, 5 is for the length of the code to be guessed and 34356 is the code itself. I splitted the String with a delimiter, but how can I hold each of its values into a variable, so I can use them later on? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ManualNumberGenerator {

    public static String input;
    public static String[] inputArray;

    public static void splitArray() {

        input = Terminal.askString("Enter some values: ");

        inputArray = input.split("DELIMITER");

        String code = Arrays.toString(inputArray);
        System.out.println(code);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        splitArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Splitting a string gives you an array already. Why you want individual variables?

Comment: Because I have to use them separately later. It will be much better when they are held by individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

This method: `public static void splitArray(){` needs to return a String array like this:

```
public static String[] splitArray(){

    ...your code
    return inputArray
}
```

Then in your main method:

```
String[] inputArray = splitArray();
```

The stringParts variable will then hold the array of inputs. You can then do what you want with the array

If you need to define individual variables you can do something like:

```
int numPossibleTried = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure the number and type of input parameters, you may want to use Scanner instead of split.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputString);
String param1 = sc.next(); // start
int param2 = sc.nextInt(); // 4
int param3 = sc.nextInt(); // 5
int param3 = sc.nextInt(); // 34356
```

Of course, you may want to check before the actual number of strings, or even check sc.hasNext() before invoking sc.next().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

In answer to the comment with the NPE, maybe you are forgetting to declare something.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanEx {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String str = "start 1 2 123455";
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
                String param1 = sc.next();
                int param2 = sc.nextInt();
                int param3 = sc.nextInt();
                int param4 = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(param1 + "\t" + param2 + "\t" + param3 + "\t" + param4);
        }
}
```

Comment: I put your code in a method holdVars(), changing the parameters to command, tries, codelength and code, adding this "System.out.println(command + tries + code + codelength);", then I called it in the main, but it gives me a NullPointerException and some other errors.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but as you said, what if I want do declare the values differently every time, so that the String str isn't constant. How do I change the code then ? Sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: I changed : String str = "start 1 2 123455";
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(str); 
to          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);